# Is there a way to measure current and fault current better than the ACS716KLATR-6BB-T

Tags: current, current-measurement, isolation, fault

I need to measure 2.5A (ac) and detect fault current. Currently I am using a Isolated Current Sensor with Overcurrent Detection ACS716KLATR-6BB-T [Datasheet](http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs/Zero-To-Fifty-Amp-Integrated-Conductor-Sensor-ICs/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ACS716-Datasheet.pdf)

I am using this part because space is the most important restraint, and of course next is cost. I need 3KV isolation as well.

My question is is there a smaller way to measure current and faults on the high side? Is there a smaller way to do this?

Working voltage is 100 - 277V (ac)

Answer (score 1):

When you say 3kV of isolation, is that your working voltage because the ACS* line are only spec'ed at 870Vpk and are dielectric tested to 3kV for 1minute.

As for space... THe ACS* from Allegro are quite compact and provide a reasonable compensated output. You will generally not get a smaller complete package.

Depending on where you are space constrained one alternative you may want to consider is a Hall Effect sensor placed over the current carrying trace (with suitable material to provide ISOLATION.

This however will require a current source (5mA) and at least one instrumentation amplifier to produce a suitable voltage output. Overall this will require a lot more real estate than a SOIC16, but you may be able to realise a more suitable physical layout.

Comment: Yes, what you say is true. I have been beating myself up for a week trying to find something better. I recently found this forum and am hoping for a miracle ;)